# JavaFX. Какое приложение открыто сейчас

Tags: java, windows, javafx

Делаю что-то типо виджета на JavaFX, мне нужно знать какое приложение сейчас открыто прямо под ним. Есть какие-либо идеи для реализации?

Answer (score -1):

Я думаю вы выбрали неподходящий язык для таких потребностей. Так как Java выполняется на виртуальной машине JRE, а JRE в свою очередь слабо связана с операционной системой и имеет ограниченный доступ к её API.